# Error in reading a massive file

Tags: r, file, data.table, read.table, write.table

I have very large text message which contain **""**,**\n** but while reading a file whose one of the column contain text is not getting read properly just because message contain **""** and **"\n"**. I have used the following

```
 dat = read.csv("abc", header=F, sep=",", quote ="\"'", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, allowEscapes=T, flush=T, comment.char="")
```

It reads file incorrectly with read.csv and reading as a table,getting an error

```
 dat = read.table("abc", header =F,sep="," , quote = "\"'",,stringsAsFactors = FALSE,allowEscapes=T,flush =T,comment.char="")
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 38 did not have 20 elements
```

So my row gets break in message column,I saved my file as  **eol** ='\r\r\n' and **quote=T** but while reading I didn't find any parameter to read it back in the same format.
saved file as

```
 write.table(z,file="abc",append=F,quote=T,sep=",",eol="\r\r\r\r\r\n",row.names=F,col.names=F)
```

in this example

```
  "In case you know,give some hint
   lot of text.....
   .................
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   \"thank you very much for your time
      and your effort\"
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------"
```

it breaks after

```
"In case you know,give some hint
   lot of text.....
   .................
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   \"thank you very much for your time
```

while reading how can i **use eol in order to retrieve complete text message in the same column** .I am not able to read a written file back,though the file successfully uploded in Mysql with loading script.Any help in this direction.
thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You'll get more help if you state exactly what error message you're getting, and show a sample of your data in a way others can easily use (ie put the csv file on a file sharing website). In any case, you probably just need to experiment with `quote = ""` and similar arguments to `read.csv` to get over this hurdle.

Comment: I edited the question and wrote error as well ,hope it is now clear.

Comment: I have tried my best to present problem , that there are some differences in parameter in write and read back.

Comment: Some1 who down voted it ,please let me know what is the reason so that i would enhance some questions in future .